# Translating a whole array continuously in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```js
var bardata = []; //array that holds the current value for the candlestick chart
  var pastRectangles = [50,12,14,15,35,64] //holds the data for the historical rectangles to be drawn
  var data;
  
  setInterval(function () {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) //generate a random whole number between 0-99
   bardata.push(x); // push that value into the bardata array
  // console.log(bardata)
   data = x; //set the value of x to data, will be used to update the pastRectangles array every 10 seconds
  }, 1000);
  
  var height = 900
   , width = 900
   , barWidth = 50
   , barOffset = 55;

  var offset = pastRectangles.length * (barOffset + barWidth);


  var scale = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([0, pastRectangles])
   .domain([0, height]);
  var svg = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg')
 
        .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)
   .style('background', 'black')
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "rectangles")
   
  
  update(pastRectangles[pastRectangles.length-1]);
  pastDraw(); // call post draw to draw the dummy data first before the update function starts running
 
  
   function pastDraw()
  {
   var pastRect = svg.selectAll('rect').data(pastRectangles);     //This function will loop through the pastRectangles array and will
      pastRect.enter()               //draw a rectange for every index in the array
    .append("rect")               //The reason for not using bardata is that it only holds one value
    .attr("g", "rectangles")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){return i * (barWidth+barOffset)})    //every second and therefore a second array is needed to hold the
    .attr("y", function(d){return height - d})        //historical data
    .attr("height", function(d){return d})         
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("id", "history")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    pastRect.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease('linear')
    .attr("height", function (d) {
     return d
    })
    pastRect.exit()
  }
  function update(bardata) {
    var rect = svg.selectAll('rect').data([bardata]);       //This function essentially draws a new rectangle for every 
    rect.enter()                //value of bardata, however, because bardata is constantly 
    .append("rect")                //removing the current value for a new value every second
    .attr("x",offset)                //it gives the illusion of one rectangle updating regularly
    .attr("y", function(d){return height - d})
    .attr("id", "updateBar")
    .attr("height", bardata)          
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    rect.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease('linear')
    .attr("height", function (d) {
     return d
    })
   
   
//    rect.exit().transition()
//          .duration(1000)
//          .attr("transform", "translate(-80,0)")
//    .remove();
//  
   
   //console.log(bardata);
  }
  function moveBar()
  {
   svg.selectAll("#history")
      .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", "translate(-80,0)")
   svg.select("#updateRect")
      .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", "translate(80,0)")
  }
 
  setInterval(function () {
   update(bardata); //call the update function with the current value of bardata
   bardata.shift(); // remove the the last index of the array from bardata
  }, 1000)
   setInterval(function () {
   pastRectangles.push(data) //update pastrectangles array with the most current value of x every 10 seconds
   pastDraw(); // call the pastDraw function to draw the latest recatngle 
   moveBar();

  }, 10000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Messing around with d3 and trying to make a live bar chart, I want it to behave like a candle stick chart 
reference image for people who dont know what that is: [image]
<sub>(source: [chart-formations.com](http://www.chart-formations.com/stock-charts/_img/candlestickChart.gif))</sub>

I want a live updating bar and after a set amount of time I want to draw a rectangle to the left of it and I've succeeded in that so far by using two arrays, one that only has one value in it every second to draw the updating bar, and another that will hold data for all the past rectangles.

The rectangles in `pastRectangles` however are being drawn in the wrong order, I can only assume this is because when d3 goes through the dataset it goes from the beginning of the array to the end of the array, I've tried reversing the array to try prevent that but still no help.

I've fixed it up and got it working somewhat how I would like it to be, however Im unable to translate it how I want it, it seems to be only translating the newest rectangle to the array and not the whole array each time, is there anyway to do that? or alternatively, move the updating bar forward each time too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of shifting the whole array of numbers to the left, I finally got the updatebar to move to the right by writing a simpe moveBars function

```
    function moveBar()
        {
            var bar = svg.selectAll("#updateBar")           
                .transition()
                .duration(50)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+move+",0)")
                move += (barWidth+barOffset);
                console.log(move)
        }
```

And then I just called that in my pastDraw() function that gets called every ten seconds

```js
 var bardata = []; //array that holds the current value for the candlestick chart
  var pastRectangles = [50,12,14,15,35,64] //holds the data for the historical rectangles to be drawn
  var data
   , height = 250
   , width = 800
   , barWidth = 50
   , barOffset= 55;
  var move = 0;
  
  
  setInterval(function () {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) //generate a random whole number between 0-99
   bardata.push(x); // push that value into the bardata array
   data = x; //set the value of x to data, will be used to update the pastRectangles array every 10 seconds
  }, 1000);
  
  data = (barOffset+barOffset)
  var offset = pastRectangles.length * (barOffset + barWidth);

  
  var scale = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([0, pastRectangles])
   .domain([0, height]);
  var svg = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)
   .style('background', 'red')
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "rectangles")
   
  
   update(pastRectangles[pastRectangles.length-1]);
   pastDraw()
   
  
   function pastDraw()
   {
    var pastRect = svg.selectAll('rect').data(pastRectangles);     //This function will loop through the pastRectangles array and will
    pastRect.enter()               //draw a rectange for every index in the array
     .append("rect")               //The reason for not using bardata is that it only holds one value
     .attr("g", "rectangles")
     .attr("x", function(d,i){return i * (barWidth+barOffset)})    //every second and therefore a second array is needed to hold the
     .attr("y", function(d){return height - d})        //historical data
     .attr("height", function(d){return d})         
     .attr("width", 60)
     .attr("id", "history")
     .attr("fill", "steelblue")
     pastRect.transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .ease('linear')
     .attr("height", function (d) {
      return d
     })
     pastRect.exit()
     var bar = svg.selectAll("#updateBar")   
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .attr("transform", "translate("+move+",0)")
     move += (barWidth+barOffset);

     
    setTimeout(function()
      {
     pastRectangles.push(data)
     
     pastDraw();
      },30000)


   }
  function update(bardata) {
    var rect = svg.selectAll('rect').data([bardata]);       //This function essentially draws a new rectangle for every 
    rect.enter()                //value of bardata, however, because bardata is constantly 
    .append("rect")                //removing the current value for a new value every second
    .attr("x",offset)                //it gives the illusion of one rectangle updating regularly
    .attr("y", function(d){return height - d})
    .attr("id", "updateBar")
    .attr("height", bardata)          
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    rect.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease('linear')
    .attr("height", function (d) {
     return d
    })
   
   
    rect.exit();
   


  
   
   //console.log(bardata);
  }
  
  setInterval(function () {
   update(bardata); //call the update function with the current value of bardata
   bardata.shift(); // remove the the last index of the array from bardata
   
  }, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

running this code on chrome can tend to stall because of how Chrome handles `SetInterval()` so instead I opted to use recursive `setTimeouts()` instead